# MySQL Group by or Distinct in Window Function

Tags: mysql

Here is a simple question I got but I want to know if there is anyone could tell me the mechanism behind the distinct and group by in window function.

I've read several posts but didn't get any related to my doubt.

Here is my question:

Regarding the following input/output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiSvU.png)

This was coming out by the following SQL query:

```
select
player_id
, first_value(event_date) over(partition by player_id order by event_date) as first_login
from Activity
group by player_id
```

I know that it can be solved by simple aggregation, don't get me wrong.
I just wonder why the 'group by' seems not working in this question, while the 'distinct' can work and pass the testing. Thank you in advance.

```
select
DISTINCT player_id
, first_value(event_date) over(partition by player_id order by event_date) as first_login
from Activity
```

If I use cute or subquery, then the 'group by' works:

```
select
*
from
(select
player_id
, first_value(event_date) over(partition by player_id order by event_date) as first_login
from Activity) as cte
group by player_id, first_login
```

Dummy Data

```
WITH 
Activity AS (
    SELECT 1 AS player_id, 2 AS device_id, '2016-03-01' AS event_date, 5 AS games_played UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 2, '2016-05-02', 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 3, '2015-06-25', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 1, '2016-03-02', 0 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 4, '2016-02-03', 5 )
```

Comment: 1) your 1st query is incorrect, Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. 2) Use MIN(), not FIRST_VALUE(). 3) Window function not needed for your task.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your comment. I know how to solve the problem, so the point is not about how to solve it. I only want to know the mechanism. However, your comment reminds me that I can check what you mentioned here: Only_Full_Group_By

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation of the difference between your queries is that there is a sequence to the operations.

1. GROUP BY reduces rows to one row per value in the grouping column (`player_id`). In your example, this results in an erroneous value, '2016-03-01' which is not the minimum value, it's just the value from the first row read during execution. This error is caused because you didn't use `sql_mode=ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.
2. Window functions apply to the rows after aggregation. If you use a window function that partitions by the same column as your grouping column, then the partitions are by definition a single row.
3. `DISTINCT` applies after window functions, reducing rows to those with a unique combination of values. This eliminates repeating rows.

Comment: Yes, all window functions are non-aggregating, aren't they? I mean, window functions calculate values by looking at multiple rows in a partition, but they do not reduce the number of rows in the result set like aggregation functions do.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This is what I'm looking for. I will check the sql mode you mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT player_id
     , MIN(event_date) AS first_login
FROM activity
GROUP BY player_id
```

Comment: Hey, thank you. But I've mentioned that I know how to solve this in other ways. Still thanks for commenting here.